# I'm getting an Error:Illegal Expression

Tags: pascal

I get this error:

```
illegal expression and Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but : found
```

The Pascal code is below:

```
Program PaidUp;

const
size=30;

var
   payment,totm1,totm2,totm3:real;
   section1,section2,section3,i,j,idnum:integer;
   IDNUMARR:array[1..999] of integer;
   PAYMENTARR:array[1..size] of real;


Procedure InitialiseVariables;
{This procedure initialises all variables used in the program}
   Begin
      idnum:=0;
      payment:=0;
      totm1:=0;
      totm2:=0;
      totm3:=0;
      section1:=0;
      section2:=0;
      section3:=0;
      i:=0;
      j:=0;
End; {Initialise Variables}

Procedure DeclareandInitialiseArrays;
{This procedure declares and initialises all arrays used in the program}
   Begin
      IDNUMARR:array[1..999] of integer;
      PAYMENTARR:array[1..size] of real;
         For i:=1 to size do
             begin
              idnum[i]:=0;
              payment[i]:=0;
         end; {ends for statment}
End; {Declare and Initialise Variables}

Procedure PutDataIntoArray;
{This procedure puts the data into the arrays}
   Begin
  while(idnum<>0 and payment<>0 and payment=1350 and payment=1620 and  payment=1800 and payment=1650 and payment=1980 and payment=2200) do
         begin
              writeln('Invalid value, please enter another value');
              readln(idnum);
              readln(payment);
         end;{ends while statement}
              set j:=j+1;
              idnum[j]:=idnum;
              payment[j]:=payment;
End; {Put Data Into Array}

 Procedure DetermineStatisticsInformation;
{This procedure determines which masqueraders belong to which group, tallys  the total persons in a section and totals the amount of money paid in each section for costumes}
   Begin
      For j:=1 to size do
         begin
              if(payment[j]=1350 and payment[j]=1650) then
                  begin
                       writeln('Masquerader with memid:idnum[j] belongs to  section1');
                       section1:= section1+1;
                       totm1:= totm1+payment[j];
                  end;{ends if statement}
              if(payment[j]=1620 and payment[j]=1980) then
                  begin
                       writeln('Masquerader with memid:idnum[j] belongs to section2');
                       section2:= section2+1;
                       totm2:=totm2+payment[j];
                  end;{ends if statement}
              if(payment[j]=1800 and payment[j]=2200)then
                  begin
                       writeln('Masquerader with memid:idnum[j] belongs to section3');
                       section3:= section3+1;
                       totm3:=totm3+payment[j];
                  end;{ends if statement}
End. {Determine Statistics Information}

Procedure PrintResults;
{This procedure outputs all information}
 Begin
  writeln('The number of masqueraders in section 1 is:', section1);
  writeln('The number of masqueraders in section 2 is:', section2);
  writeln('The number of masqueraders in section 3 is:', section3);
  writeln('Total Amount of money paid in section 1 is:', totm1);
  writeln('Total Amount of money paid in section 2 is:', totm2);
  writeln('Total Amount of money paid in section 3 is:', totm3);
End. {Print Results}
```

Comment: oh i did it in modular format because my professor said too

Comment: Did the compiler tell you what lines the errors occurred on?  That would be good information to include in your question.

Comment: yes they fell on both 31/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is full of errors and would never compile.

1. You use idnum and payment as array but you've declared it as integer! If you need the array, use IDNUMARR and PAYMENTARR instead.
2. In line 9 and 10 you declare the global var IDNUMARR PAYMENTARR but you declare it again as a local var in the procedure DeclareandInitialiseArrays
3. Almost all if-statements are invalid

   if(payment[j]=1620 and payment[j]=1980) then

The "and" operator is evaluated always first which results in the logical comparison "1620 and payment[j]" (which is not a valid syntax).

You have to put every comparison into brackets like this:

```
if(payment[j]=1620) and (payment[j]=1980) then
```

4. set j:=j+1; 
What exactly do you expect should happen??
I think you just want increase j

```
j:=j+1;
```

5. All procedures have to end with ; and not .
6. the final "begin end." is missing where you execute all your program.

And probably many others...

Comment: um...thank you but like i said im VERY new to this type of software...like 2 days new...dont get me wrong im extremely grateful for your answer and i will try my best to fix it....can i ask one more question? do u mean that to use PAYMENTARR where i have payment[j]?

Comment: Yes. Your array variables are PAYMENTARR and IDNUMARR. So you have to use PAYMENTARR[j] and IDNUMARR[j]

Comment: ohhh ok, i believed i have fixed what was wrong....so im reuploading what i did... and Thank You for your continued Support!

Comment: um...i dont know how to repost the entire code can u tell me how too? xD

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong, and other lines like it:

```
  if(payment[j]=1350 and payment[j]=1650) then
```

Make it look like   if  (..) and (..) then

Comment: oh ok thank you ill fix what u guys have said to fix and i will reupload for re-evaluation by you fine folks...Thank You for your help

Comment: @Josiah, if you make substantial changes to your code and you still have questions, it would be better to accept one of the answers on this question (if they were helpful), then post a new question with any new issues.  If you change the code in this question, it will invalidate the answers you've already received...that's not how the site is supposed to work.

Comment: @JimLewis oki i will and ill repost