# Illegal Expression's Pascal (New Errors)

Tags: pascal

```
Program PaidUp;

const
size=30;

var
  payment,totm1,totm2,totm3:real;
  section1,section2,section3,i,j,idnum:integer;
  IDNUMARR:array[1..999] of integer;
  PAYMENTARR:array[1..size] of real;


Procedure InitialiseVariables;
{This procedure initialises all variables used in the program}
Begin
  idnum:=0;
  payment:=0;
  totm1:=0;
  totm2:=0;
  totm3:=0;
  section1:=0;
  section2:=0;
  section3:=0;
  i:=0;
  j:=0;
 End; {Initialise Variables}

Procedure DeclareandInitialiseArrays;
{This procedure declares and initialises all arrays used in the program}
  Begin
     For i:=1 to size do
         begin
              IDNUMARR[i]:=0;
              PAYMENTARR[i]:=0;
         end; {ends for statment}
End; {Declare and Initialise Variables}

Procedure PutDataIntoArray;
{This procedure puts the data into the arrays}
Begin
  while(idnum<>0) and (payment<>0) and (payment=1350) and (payment=1620) and            (payment=1800) and (payment=1650) and (payment=1980) and (payment=2200) do
         begin
              writeln('Invalid value, please enter another value');
              readln(idnum);
              readln(payment);
         end;{ends while statement}
              j:=j+1;
              IDNUMARR[j]:=idnum;
              PAYMENTARR[j]:=payment;
End; {Put Data Into Array}

Procedure DetermineStatisticsInformation;
{This procedure determines which masqueraders belong to which group, tallys the total persons in a section and totals the amount of money paid in each section for costumes}
 Begin
  For j:=1 to size do
         begin
              if(PAYMENTARR[j]=1350) and (PAYMENTARR[j]=1650) then
                  begin
                       writeln('Masquerader with memid:idnum[j] belongs to section1');
                       section1:= section1+1;
                       totm1:= totm1+PAYMENTARR[j];
                  end;{ends if statement}
              if(PAYMENTARR[j]=1620) and (PAYMENTARR[j]=1980) then
                  begin
                       writeln('Masquerader with memid:idnum[j] belongs to section2');
                       section2:= section2+1;
                       totm2:=totm2+PAYMENTARR[j];
                  end;{ends if statement}
              if(PAYMENTARR[j]=1800) and (PAYMENTARR[j]=2200)then
                  begin
                       writeln('Masquerader with memid:idnum[j] belongs to section3');
                       section3:= section3+1;
                       totm3:=totm3+PAYMENTARR[j];
                  end;{ends if statement}
End; {Determine Statistics Information}

Procedure PrintResults;
{This procedure outputs all information}
Begin
  writeln('The number of masqueraders in section 1 is:', section1);
  writeln('The number of masqueraders in section 2 is:', section2);
  writeln('The number of masqueraders in section 3 is:', section3);
  writeln('Total Amount of money paid in section 1 is:', totm1);
  writeln('Total Amount of money paid in section 2 is:', totm2);
  writeln('Total Amount of money paid in section 3 is:', totm3);
End. {Print Results}
```

The errors i got were: 77 / 11 paidup.pas Error: Illegal expression
                       77 / 11 paidup.pas Error: Illegal expression
                       77 / 11 paidup.pas Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but identifier PRINTRESULTS found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting an Error:Illegal Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005450/im-getting-an-errorillegal-expression)

Comment: Why do you post the same problem as a new topic? The answer was already given in your first question in point 5 and 6

Comment: i did what u said to do but the guy said if i changed it i should repost it if i get any new errors so i did

Comment: besides i got new errors, but with penguino's help i got it and yours mate..so Cheers to you all!! Thank You All

Comment: Please stop posting huge walls of code every time you run into a problem. See the [help], specifically the [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At least make an effort to properly format your code so it's not such a mess - there's formatting help available by clicking the round **?** icon on the right of the toolbar. Asking you to repost if you have more problems does **NOT** mean *feel free to dump your entire code here as a total horrible difficult to read mess and expect us to sort it out for you*.

Comment: Sorry.... im new to this forum as well.. ill keep that in mind... BTW TO ALL GUYS THAT HELPED THANK YOU!! THE PROGRAM IS WORKING NOW!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *still* missing an end statement to match the begin statement that follows **For j:=1 to size do** in procedure **DetermineStatisticsInformation**.

Also, your while condition **while(idnum<>0) and (payment<>0) and (payment=1350) and (payment=1620) and (payment=1800) and (payment=1650) and (payment=1980) and (payment=2200) do** in procedure **PutDataIntoArray** will never be true as it is impossible for **payment** to simultaneously be equal to 1350 and equal to 1620 etc...

Comment: ohh ok, my teacher had said to do it like that.. so ill discss that part with her...but i thank you for the clarification of that first part...i would also like to apologize for my tardiness to fix all the errors you guys tell me to fix..so thank you for bearing with me

Comment: @JosiahMarcano if you formatted your code properly, with consistent indentation, the missing `end` would have been quite obvious.

Comment: @lurker well i jus started using pascal a couple days ago without any prior knowledge of how to do little things such as the thing with the IF statements so...yeah

Comment: @JosiahMarcano it was just a little friendly advice. :) Have you programmed in any other languages before? Consistent code formatting is a fundamental part of programming in any language.

Comment: @lurker no i havent...im a young student...i have only done basic stuff such as writing pseudocode algorithms and drawing up Flow Charts and stuff..it's my first time using pascal